# Detecting the existance of the cut

Tags: algorithm, graph

we have an undirected graph G = (V,E) with n nodes and m edges, i want to calculate whether G have a cut of size m or not ? How can I solve it ? I tried BFS but i realized that we can calculate with lower or upper level for cut.

Edit: The cut just separates the graph in two pieces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is a sub-case of [the maximum cut problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_cut). Note that the maximum-cut problem asks for a cut of at least an arbitrary value `x`, not necessarily `m`. It is thus more general than what you asked for.

Max-Cut is NP-complete, meaning that there is no known algorithm in polynomial time. The best know algorithm is trying out every possible cut (brute search).

A max-cut may look like the following picture. Generally it does NOT look like something that you'd create with BFS or DFS.

[image: maximum cut in a small graph]

In this sub-problem you are lucky though: First off, the edges are unweighted, meaning that indirectly all of them have a weight of 1. If they were weighted, my proposed solution would be invalid.

If there is a max-cut of size m, this means that every edge is part of the cut. This is equivalent to the test of [bipartness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph). This is possible to check in linear time. Here is an example of a biparte graph:
[image: a biparte graph]

To conclude: The question "does Graph G have a cut of size of at least x" is NP-complete, but your question is equivalent to test of bipartness. A graph is biparte exactly if it doesn't contain any circles of uneven length. Here is the [algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bipartite-graph/) to test for bipartness, which runs in O(V+E), just like BFS.

Comment: Re: "This problem is NP-complete, meaning that there is no know solution except of trying every single possible cut in this graph": That's not actually what "NP-complete" means. There's no known worst-case polynomial-time solution, but a solution needn't necessarily check every single possible cut. (Your last paragraph demonstrates this, by giving an algorithm that skips certain cuts in certain cases.)

Comment: The problem being NP-complete does not mean that special cases may have a better runtime. I will try to clarify my answer. But you could for example also think about indipendent set in a graph with no edges (even though that is pretty pointless).

Comment: Also yes, you're right, my definition of NP-complete was not exact, I wanted to keep it short and easy, because I guessed OP didn't know this concept before, elsewise he would have propably heard of the max-cut problem

Comment: Yeah, i did not mentioned the graph cut should just separate the graph in two pieces.Sorry about that. But i do not find out that how to detect the cut size with testing of bipartiteness ? @Morinator

Comment: Sorry, I did not include that. I do that now. It is to test if there are circles of odd length. Also "cut" implies that it is about two pieces, so you did nothing wrong.

Comment: Also I wonder that you mentioned in above "it is unweighted". So what about weighted graph is there still a solution to that?@Morinator

Comment: There is also a bigger problem called weighted maximum cut, which is not what you need here. I just wanted to point out that there is a distinction, since you didnt mention it in your question. What I posted I is regarding the unweighted case, so dont worry.

Comment: Could you share a link or description for that i just want to learned it too.@Morinator

Comment: For example here: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15854-f05/www/scribe/lec07.pdf. Search for "weighted max cut". It is a harder problem and (I think) less popular/studied, and also harder, because it includes the unweighted case. What you also see in this paper is that this problem is so hard that you try to approximate it as closely as possible with different techniques, elsewise you may wait thousands of years until your program terminates.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210770/discussion-between-morinator-and-leo-s).